# How do I align my logo left of an h1 heading?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align my logo next to the h1, but the logo always goes above it. I'm a beginner to html and css. I tried all other answers in Stack Overflow.
Here’s my code:

```html
 <div class="logo float-left">
<img src="img/gostack.png" id="yourlogo" alt="The only logo">        <h1 class="text-light" ><a href="#intro" class="scrollto"><span><strong>GoStack</strong></span></a></h1>
 </div>
```

Comment: To solve this it would be helpful to have the CSS for float-left and other classes as well as screen shot and to note what browser this behavior is observed in.

Answer (score 1):

You have not added the class (css) float left.
I have added css here is the code

**HTML**

```
 <div class="cust-container">
<img src="img/gostack.png" id="yourlogo" alt="The only logo" class='iconDetails'>
    <h1 class="text-light" ><a href="#intro" class="scrollto"><span><strong>GoStack</strong></span></a></h1>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.cust-container {
width:100%;
height:auto;
padding:1%;
}

.iconDetails {
 margin-left:2%;
 float:left; 
 height:40px;
 width:40px;    
 } 

h1 {
  margin:0px;
}
```

Here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/Arpit09/fwxjvy1d/4/

Answer (score 1):

In HTML, block elements expand to fill all available horizontal space, forcing all other elements to flow either above or below the responsible element. To fix this, you can either change the display properties of your elements or use something like CSS Grid or Flex. I recommend just adding `display: flex` to your `.logo` class

```css
.logo{
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo float-left">
<img src="img/gostack.png" id="yourlogo" alt="The only logo"><h1 class="text-light" ><a href="#intro" class="scrollto"><span><strong>GoStack</strong></span></a></h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a class "inline" in your h1 and add this CSS property to it:

```css
.inline {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo float-left">
<img src="img/gostack.png" id="yourlogo" alt="The only logo">
<h1 class="text-light inline" ><a href="#intro" class="scrollto"><span><strong>GoStack</strong></span></a></h1>
 </div>
```

Comment: No point in making your code a snippet if it doesn't show anything helpful

Comment: Sorry, correcting my answer

Comment: Don't remove the snippet, instead add relavant html to illustrate your solution.

Comment: Added. Thank you